# Where am I able to see the launch template used for an Ec2 machine in AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I would like to know my launch template, which I used for my ec2 machine.

I know, that the is function, which is able to achieve this by **get-launch-template-data**, but I would like to see it in the management console.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Click on the instance you want to check. In the tags section, there is a tag called `aws:ec2launchtemplate:version` which shows the template version number used to run the particular instance.

Alternatively, if you are using auto-scaling groups, there is an instance management and it shows a table of instances running within the group including the launch template used for each instance.